# How to use display different menu based on different react router path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

I am working on a react project I have the site home page with the default navbar but I want the site dashboard to have a different navbar from the site other pages.

I have tried to create 2 `<Layout> components` that takes children and display different Navbar. I then wrap my components with them depending on the Navbar I want to show. But react-router is having a problem with this. Below is my code:

```
<>
      <Switch>

        <Route exact path="/admin/login" component={ Login } />

        <Dashboard>
          <Route exact path="/admin/dashboard/" component={ DashboardHome } />
          <Route exact path="/admin/dashboard/about" component={ AboutForm } />
          <Route exact path="/admin/dashboard/properties" component={ Allproperties } />
          <Route exact path="/admin/dashboard/contact" component={ ContactFrom } />
          <Route exact path="/admin/dashboard/newproperty" component={ Newproperty } />
          {/* <Route exact path="/admin/dashboard/messages" component={ Messages } /> */}
        </Dashboard>

        <Layout>
          <Route exact path="/" component={ Home } /> 
          <Route exact path="/properties/" component={ Properties } />
          <Route exact path="/services/" component={ Services } />
          <Route exact path="/contact/" component={ ContactMe } />
          <Route exact path="/property/:slug" component={ SingleProperty } />
          <Route component={ Errors } />
        </Layout>

      </Switch>
    </>
```

The code for the Layout component:

```
import React from 'react';

// components
import Navbar from './Navbar'

const Layout = ({children}) => {
    return (
        <>
            <Navbar />
            {children}
        </>
    );

}

export default Layout;
```

The code for the dashboard Layout component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

// style
import './Dashboard.css'

// components
import DashboardNav from '../components/DashboardNav'

const Dashboard = ({ children }) => {

    return (
        <section className="">
            <div className="row">
                <div id="main" className="col-sm-12 d-flex">
                    <aside id="sidebar" className="dashboard col-md-2 bg-secondary">
                        <ul className="nav flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
                            <li className="nav-item py-md-4 px-md-3">
                                <Link className="nav-link active text-white" to="#">Logo</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item p-md-3">
                                <Link className="nav-link active text-white" to="#">Dashboard</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item p-md-3">
                                <Link className="nav-link text-white" to="#">All Properties</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item p-md-3">
                                <Link className="nav-link text-white" to="#">New Properties</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item p-md-3">
                                <Link className="nav-link text-white" to="#">Messages</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item p-md-3">
                                <Link className="nav-link text-white" to="#">About</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item p-md-3">
                                <Link className="nav-link text-white" to="#">Contact</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item p-md-3">
                                <Link className="nav-link text-white" to="#">Blog</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item p-md-3">
                                <Link className="nav-link text-white" to="#">Logout</Link>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </aside>

                    <article id="dashboard" className="col-sm-12 col-md-10">
                        <header id="menu" className="dashboard d-flex flex-column">
                            <DashboardNav />
                        </header>

                        <main className="py-md-3">

                            {/* { loading && <Loading /> } */}
                            { children }

                        </main>
                    </article>                        
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    )

}

export default Dashboard
```

When I navigate to the route `localhost:3000/admin/dashboard` everything works fine including all the route along the `/admin/dashboard/*` the problem is when I navigate to `localhost:3000` it still shows the dashboard.

I know there is a way to implement this. But being my first time I am having a hard time implementing it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why are seeing dashboard menu even on the localhost:3000/ is because `Dashboard` component is actually rendered on that page. Of course, the content component inside `Dashboard` component which are wrapped with react router, including `DashboardHome` and `AboutForm` are not displayed on that page, but the dashboard menus are not wrapped with react router.

Please try to update your components in this way.

Main Router:

```
<>
   <Switch>
       <Route exact path="/admin/login" component={ Login } />
       <Route path="/admin" component={ Dashboard } />
       <Route path="/" component={ Layout } />
   </Switch>
</>
```

Dashboard:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

// style
import './Dashboard.css'

// components
import DashboardNav from '../components/DashboardNav'

const Dashboard = ({ children }) => {

    return (
        <section className="">
            <div className="row">
                <div id="main" className="col-sm-12 d-flex">
                    <aside id="sidebar" className="dashboard col-md-2 bg-secondary">
                        <ul className="nav flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
                            <li className="nav-item py-md-4 px-md-3">
                                <Link className="nav-link active text-white" to="#">Logo</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item p-md-3">
                                <Link className="nav-link active text-white" to="#">Dashboard</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item p-md-3">
                                <Link className="nav-link text-white" to="#">All Properties</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item p-md-3">
                                <Link className="nav-link text-white" to="#">New Properties</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item p-md-3">
                                <Link className="nav-link text-white" to="#">Messages</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item p-md-3">
                                <Link className="nav-link text-white" to="#">About</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item p-md-3">
                                <Link className="nav-link text-white" to="#">Contact</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item p-md-3">
                                <Link className="nav-link text-white" to="#">Blog</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item p-md-3">
                                <Link className="nav-link text-white" to="#">Logout</Link>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </aside>

                    <article id="dashboard" className="col-sm-12 col-md-10">
                        <header id="menu" className="dashboard d-flex flex-column">
                            <DashboardNav />
                        </header>

                        <main className="py-md-3">

                            {/* { loading && <Loading /> } */}
                            <Switch>
                                <Route exact path="/admin/dashboard/" component={ DashboardHome } />
                                <Route exact path="/admin/dashboard/about" component={ AboutForm } />
                                <Route exact path="/admin/dashboard/properties" component={ Allproperties } />
                                <Route exact path="/admin/dashboard/contact" component={ ContactFrom } />
                                <Route exact path="/admin/dashboard/newproperty" component={ Newproperty } />
                                {/* <Route exact path="/admin/dashboard/messages" component={ Messages } /> */}
                            </Switch>

                        </main>
                    </article>                        
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    )

}

export default Dashboard
```

Layout:

```
import React from 'react';

// components
import Navbar from './Navbar'

const Layout = ({children}) => {
    return (
        <>
            <Navbar />
            <Switch>
               <Route exact path="/" component={ Home } /> 
               <Route exact path="/properties/" component={ Properties } />
               <Route exact path="/services/" component={ Services } />
               <Route exact path="/contact/" component={ ContactMe } />
               <Route exact path="/property/:slug" component={ SingleProperty } />
               <Route component={ Errors } />
            </Switch>
        </>
    );

}

export default Layout;
```